# Possible DOS Attack? And solutions for it?

Tags: attacks, denial-of-service

I don't know whether it's appropriate to post this question here but I desperately need help.

I've been receiving ping requests from 18 different IP addresses so far. Some of them are local, some are from US and Russia. In half an hour, my router dropped 220 ping requests.
And last night, my router logged that there's SYN Flooding attacks, TELNET requests, and SYN-FIN attack

It got me disconnected from the net quite a lot of times. So, are the ping requests a DoS attack or it's really THAT NORMAL to have so many ping in such a short amount of time. And also, any solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The average internet-facing IP address receives dozens of attempted attacks per day, let alone random probes and port scans.

Comment: well, the IP addresses are consistent and still pinging. and I guess random scans wouldn't block themselves from being scanned right? not to mention to the extent of disconnecting me from the net o_O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

220 ping requests hardly qualify as [DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). A [SYN flood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood) is a kind of DoS, and if your router is reporting a SYN flood then chances are that there *is* someone playing at pestering you with low-scale DoS. The ping requests are not part of that attack, but may be used by the attackers to monitor whether the attack works or not (i.e. whether they could crash your router or not).

Usual mitigation against such attacks is simply to wait for the attacker to get bored or to reach the age of 13, whichever comes first. You may want to alert your ISP, though (don't tell them "I am being attacked" but rather "I get disconnected and my router shows this strange error message"; disconnections are part of the scope of their job and if some formal complain must be made with law enforcement agencies then having the ISP handle part of it would be a good idea).

Comment: well, since you experts say that it's not a DoS. I am now a happy man, for now at least..